# How to optimize recursive code to calculate beauty of an array?

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming

You have an array of integers. You can delete as many elements as you can from the array and return the maximum beauty of the array. Beauty of the array is number of elements in the array which have same value as it's index.
eg: arr = [1,3,3] has beauty of 2. elements at index 0(1) and index 2(3) are part of beautiful array. i.e. index 0 is considered position 1.

**My attempt:**

```
int rec(vector<int> arr, int i, int n, int rem, int curCount) (
    if (i == n){
        return curCount;
    }
    int ans = 0;
    if (arr [i] == i - rem + 1) {
        ans = max (ans, rec(arr, i+1, n, rem, curCount + 1)) ;
    }
    else{
        ans = max(ans, rec(arr, i+1, n, rem, curCount));
    }
        ans = max(ans, rec(arr, i+1, n, rem, curCount));
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: `int rec(vector<int> arr, int i, int n, int rem, int curCount)` -- Stop passing `arr` by value.

Comment: Note: I think your program has a bug because `n` is never modified so the base case will never occur (unless you pass 1 to n when you call it).

Comment: There is a mistake in my code it should have been i == n instead of 1 == n.
I am looking for some solution where we don't have to recursively call every single possible permutation.

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's try another dynamic-programming attempt (since my previous one was incorrect).

Let B[i] be the "best beauty" [sic] recorded to date for a part-array of length i. Then as you consider each new element there are only two choices for an updated B[i]:

> take the previous best of length i-1 and include the new element in the array;

or

> keep the previous best of length i and don't include the new element

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int beauty( const vector<int> &A )
{
   vector<int> B( 1 + A.size(), 0 );
   int N = A.size();
   for ( int pos = 1; pos <= N; pos++ )
   {
      auto B_old = B;
      int a = A[pos-1];      // index is (position - 1)
      for ( int length = 1; length <= pos; length++ )
      {
         B[length] = max( B_old[length-1] + ( a == length ), B_old[length] );
      }
   }

   return *max_element( B.begin(), B.end() );
}

//======================================================================

int main()
{
   vector< vector<int> > tests = {
                                   { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                                   { 4, 3, 2, 1 },
                                   { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
                                   { 1, 4, 2, 3 },
                                   { 1, 4, 2, 5 },
                                   { 1, 3, 3 },
                                   { 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 3} 
                                 };
   for ( const auto &A : tests ) cout << beauty( A ) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
4
1
0
3
2
2
4
```